# Update all layers of git submodules from the top level repo. (Could not access submodule)

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo called 'c'. In this git repository, i have another repository called 'SuperText' and then, in the 'SuperText' repository i have 3 other repos, called LANP2PText, WANClientText and WANServerText. What i want to do, it's that when i write 'git pull' in the c/ repository, it pulls all repos and sub-repos recursively. I need this to apply to any new submodule created anywhere on the submodule tree.

I looked for documentation and did all of this :

```
astramast@astraputer:~/c$ git --version 
git version 2.34.1
astramast@astraputer:~/c$ git config --global submodule.recurse true
astramast@astraputer:~/c$ git submodule update --init --recursive --remote 
Fetching submodule LANP2PText
Fetching submodule WANClientText
Fetching submodule WANServerText
astramast@astraputer:~/c$ cd perso/SuperText/
astramast@astraputer:~/c/perso/SuperText$ git submodule update --init --recursive --remote 
astramast@astraputer:~/c/perso/SuperText$ cd ../..
astramast@astraputer:~/c$ cat .gitmodules 
[submodule "perso/SuperText"]
        path = perso/SuperText
        url = https://github.com/Astramast/SuperText.git
astramast@astraputer:~/c$ cat perso/SuperText/.gitmodules 
[submodule "LANP2PText"]
        path = LANP2PText
        url = https://github.com/Astramast/LANP2PText.git
[submodule "WANServerText"]
        path = WANServerText
        url = https://github.com/Astramast/WANServerText.git
[submodule "WANClientText"]
        path = WANClientText
        url = https://github.com/Astramast/WANClientText.git
astramast@astraputer:~/c$ git pull
Fetching submodule perso/SuperText
Could not access submodule 'LANP2PText'
Could not access submodule 'WANClientText'
Could not access submodule 'WANServerText'
Errors during submodule fetch:
        perso/SuperText
astramast@astraputer:~/c$ cd perso/SuperText/
astramast@astraputer:~/c/perso/SuperText$ git pull
Fetching submodule LANP2PText
Fetching submodule WANClientText
Fetching submodule WANServerText
Already up to date.
```

As you can see Git somehow cannot access to the submodules under its direct layer. I do not know how to fix this.

Someone told me to run this :

```
astramast@astraputer:~/c$ GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRACE2=1 git pull
09:30:36.039269 common-main.c:48                  version 2.34.1
09:30:36.039291 common-main.c:49                  start git pull
09:30:36.039419 compat/linux/procinfo.c:170       cmd_ancestry bash <- qterminal <- gnome-session-b <- systemd <- systemd
09:30:36.039544 repository.c:132                  worktree /home/astramast/c
09:30:36.039632 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git pull
09:30:36.039645 git.c:456                         cmd_name pull (pull)
09:30:36.039981 run-command.c:740                 child_start[0] git fetch --update-head-ok --recurse-submodules=on
09:30:36.039997 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok --recurse-submodules=on
09:30:36.041919 common-main.c:48                  version 2.34.1
09:30:36.041940 common-main.c:49                  start /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --update-head-ok --recurse-submodules=on
09:30:36.042094 compat/linux/procinfo.c:170       cmd_ancestry git <- bash <- qterminal <- gnome-session-b <- systemd <- systemd
09:30:36.042205 repository.c:132                  worktree /home/astramast/c
09:30:36.042292 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git fetch --update-head-ok --recurse-submodules=on
09:30:36.042307 git.c:456                         cmd_name fetch (pull/fetch)
09:30:36.042614 run-command.c:740                 child_start[0] git remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/c.git
09:30:36.042630 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/c.git
09:30:36.044474 common-main.c:48                  version 2.34.1
09:30:36.044494 common-main.c:49                  start /usr/lib/git-core/git remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/c.git
09:30:36.044672 compat/linux/procinfo.c:170       cmd_ancestry git <- git <- bash <- qterminal <- gnome-session-b <- systemd <- systemd
09:30:36.044795 git.c:736                         cmd_name _run_dashed_ (pull/fetch/_run_dashed_)
09:30:36.044805 git.c:742               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/c.git
09:30:36.044818 run-command.c:740                 child_start[0] git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/c.git
09:30:36.044825 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/c.git
09:30:36.051862 common-main.c:48                  version 2.34.1
09:30:36.051887 common-main.c:49                  start /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/c.git
09:30:36.052091 compat/linux/procinfo.c:170       cmd_ancestry git <- git <- git <- bash <- qterminal <- gnome-session-b <- systemd <- systemd
09:30:36.052170 repository.c:132                  worktree /home/astramast/c
09:30:36.052198 remote-curl.c:1493                cmd_name remote-curl (pull/fetch/_run_dashed_/remote-curl)
09:30:41.690925 run-command.c:740                 child_start[0] 'git credential-store get'
09:30:41.690962 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: 'git credential-store get'
09:30:41.695577 common-main.c:48                  version 2.34.1
09:30:41.695605 common-main.c:49                  start git credential-store get
09:30:41.695871 compat/linux/procinfo.c:170       cmd_ancestry sh <- git-remote-http <- git <- git <- git <- bash <- qterminal <- gnome-session-b <- systemd <- systemd
09:30:41.695908 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git credential-store get
09:30:41.695919 git.c:456                         cmd_name credential-store (pull/fetch/_run_dashed_/remote-curl/credential-store)
09:30:41.696021 git.c:713                         exit elapsed:0.000856 code:0
09:30:41.696034 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:0.000872 code:0
09:30:41.696513 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[0] pid:5780 code:0 elapsed:0.005580
09:30:44.565713 run-command.c:740                 child_start[1] 'git credential-store store'
09:30:44.565751 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: 'git credential-store store'
09:30:44.569525 common-main.c:48                  version 2.34.1
09:30:44.569538 common-main.c:49                  start git credential-store store
09:30:44.569684 compat/linux/procinfo.c:170       cmd_ancestry sh <- git-remote-http <- git <- git <- git <- bash <- qterminal <- gnome-session-b <- systemd <- systemd
09:30:44.569699 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git credential-store store
09:30:44.569705 git.c:456                         cmd_name credential-store (pull/fetch/_run_dashed_/remote-curl/credential-store)
09:30:44.570004 git.c:713                         exit elapsed:0.000726 code:0
09:30:44.570012 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:0.000739 code:0
09:30:44.570432 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[1] pid:5782 code:0 elapsed:0.004716
09:30:47.386968 run-command.c:740                 child_start[1] git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs
09:30:47.387000 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs
09:30:47.391357 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[1] pid:5784 code:0 elapsed:0.004385
09:30:47.394073 common-main.c:54                  exit elapsed:11.342513 code:0
09:30:47.394105 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:11.342559 code:0
09:30:47.395814 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[0] pid:5776 code:0 elapsed:11.350984
09:30:47.395851 git.c:758                         exit elapsed:11.351737 code:0
09:30:47.395861 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:11.351748 code:0
09:30:47.396293 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[0] pid:5775 code:0 elapsed:11.353671
09:30:47.396536 run-command.c:1597      run_processes_parallel: preparing to run up to 1 tasks
09:30:47.396682 repository.c:132                  worktree /home/astramast/c/perso/SuperText
09:30:47.396721 run-command.c:740                 child_start[2] cd /home/astramast/c/perso/SuperText/.git; git fetch --no-prune --no-prune-tags --update-head-ok --recurse-submodules --recurse-submodules-default yes --submodule-prefix perso/SuperText/
09:30:47.396748 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: cd /home/astramast/c/perso/SuperText/.git; unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_DIR=. git fetch --no-prune --no-prune-tags --update-head-ok --recurse-submodules --recurse-submodules-default yes --submodule-prefix perso/SuperText/
Fetching submodule perso/SuperText
09:30:47.398992 common-main.c:48                  version 2.34.1
09:30:47.399013 common-main.c:49                  start /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --no-prune --no-prune-tags --update-head-ok --recurse-submodules --recurse-submodules-default yes --submodule-prefix perso/SuperText/
09:30:47.399231 compat/linux/procinfo.c:170       cmd_ancestry git <- git <- bash <- qterminal <- gnome-session-b <- systemd <- systemd
09:30:47.399358 repository.c:132                  worktree /home/astramast/c/perso/SuperText/.git
09:30:47.399479 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git fetch --no-prune --no-prune-tags --update-head-ok --recurse-submodules --recurse-submodules-default yes --submodule-prefix perso/SuperText/
09:30:47.399491 git.c:456                         cmd_name fetch (pull/fetch/fetch)
09:30:47.400284 run-command.c:740                 child_start[0] git remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/SuperText.git
09:30:47.400302 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/SuperText.git
09:30:47.402818 common-main.c:48                  version 2.34.1
09:30:47.402841 common-main.c:49                  start /usr/lib/git-core/git remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/SuperText.git
09:30:47.403133 compat/linux/procinfo.c:170       cmd_ancestry git <- git <- git <- bash <- qterminal <- gnome-session-b <- systemd <- systemd
09:30:47.403302 git.c:736                         cmd_name _run_dashed_ (pull/fetch/fetch/_run_dashed_)
09:30:47.403312 git.c:742               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/SuperText.git
09:30:47.403329 run-command.c:740                 child_start[0] git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/SuperText.git
09:30:47.403337 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/SuperText.git
09:30:47.412908 common-main.c:48                  version 2.34.1
09:30:47.412934 common-main.c:49                  start /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Astramast/SuperText.git
09:30:47.413225 compat/linux/procinfo.c:170       cmd_ancestry git <- git <- git <- git <- bash <- qterminal <- gnome-session-b <- systemd <- systemd
09:30:47.413332 repository.c:132                  worktree /home/astramast/c/perso/SuperText/.git
09:30:47.413371 remote-curl.c:1493                cmd_name remote-curl (pull/fetch/fetch/_run_dashed_/remote-curl)
09:30:56.556395 run-command.c:740                 child_start[1] git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs
09:30:56.556419 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs
09:30:56.560618 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[1] pid:5792 code:0 elapsed:0.004225
09:30:56.563610 common-main.c:54                  exit elapsed:9.151141 code:0
09:30:56.563638 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:9.151179 code:0
09:30:56.565470 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[0] pid:5787 code:0 elapsed:9.162132
09:30:56.565497 git.c:758                         exit elapsed:9.163158 code:0
09:30:56.565513 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:9.163174 code:0
09:30:56.565897 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[0] pid:5786 code:0 elapsed:9.165608
09:30:56.566147 run-command.c:1597      run_processes_parallel: preparing to run up to 1 tasks
09:30:56.566309 run-command.c:1629      run_processes_parallel: done
Could not access submodule 'LANP2PText'
Could not access submodule 'WANClientText'
Could not access submodule 'WANServerText'
09:30:56.566330 run-command.c:740                 child_start[2] git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
09:30:56.566339 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
09:30:56.568320 common-main.c:48                  version 2.34.1
09:30:56.568339 common-main.c:49                  start /usr/lib/git-core/git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
09:30:56.568528 compat/linux/procinfo.c:170       cmd_ancestry git <- git <- git <- bash <- qterminal <- gnome-session-b <- systemd <- systemd
09:30:56.568654 repository.c:132                  worktree /home/astramast/c/perso/SuperText/.git
09:30:56.568757 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
09:30:56.568770 git.c:456                         cmd_name maintenance (pull/fetch/fetch/maintenance)
09:30:56.569088 git.c:713                         exit elapsed:0.001120 code:0
09:30:56.569101 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:0.001136 code:0
09:30:56.569381 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[2] pid:5793 code:0 elapsed:0.003045
09:30:56.569402 git.c:713                         exit elapsed:9.170820 code:1
09:30:56.569410 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:9.170828 code:1
09:30:56.569769 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[2] pid:5785 code:1 elapsed:9.173043
09:30:56.569806 run-command.c:1629      run_processes_parallel: done
Errors during submodule fetch:
        perso/SuperText
09:30:56.569852 run-command.c:740                 child_start[3] git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
09:30:56.569861 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
09:30:56.571937 common-main.c:48                  version 2.34.1
09:30:56.571958 common-main.c:49                  start /usr/lib/git-core/git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
09:30:56.572120 compat/linux/procinfo.c:170       cmd_ancestry git <- git <- bash <- qterminal <- gnome-session-b <- systemd <- systemd
09:30:56.572239 repository.c:132                  worktree /home/astramast/c
09:30:56.572323 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
09:30:56.572334 git.c:456                         cmd_name maintenance (pull/fetch/maintenance)
09:30:56.572618 git.c:713                         exit elapsed:0.001019 code:0
09:30:56.572631 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:0.001035 code:0
09:30:56.572901 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[3] pid:5794 code:0 elapsed:0.003044
09:30:56.572929 git.c:713                         exit elapsed:20.531380 code:1
09:30:56.572938 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:20.531389 code:1
09:30:56.573332 run-command.c:996                 child_exit[0] pid:5774 code:1 elapsed:20.533343
09:30:56.573366 git.c:713                         exit elapsed:20.534530 code:1
09:30:56.573376 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:20.534541 code:1
```

Comment: To try to understand what is wrong, maybe running with `GIT_TRACE=1`, `GIT_TRACE2=1`, would help.

Comment: Here you go, i can't really know what it says. Does it help ?

Comment: unfortunately it does not help, I had hoped that we would see the repertory where Git expected the submodules to be found... Is your repository called 'c' public ? can you create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? Ideally starting with `git clone` (or `git init`)